# Delayed dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_hdf computations crashing

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I'm using Dask to to execute the following logic:

- read in a master delayed `dd.DataFrame` from multiple input files (one `pd.DataFrame` per file)
- perform multiple `query` calls on the master delayed DataFrame
- use `DataFrame.to_hdf` to save all dataframes from the `DataFrame.query` calls.

If I use `compute=False` in my `to_hdf` calls and feed the list of `Delayed`s returned by each `to_hdf` call to `dask.compute` then I get a crash/seg fault. (If I omit `compute=False` everything runs fine). Some googling gave me some information about locks; I tried adding a `dask.distributed.Client` with a `dask.distributed.Lock` fed to `to_hdf`, as well as a `dask.utils.SerializableLock`, but I couldn't solve the crash.

here's the flow:

```py
import uproot
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.delayed import delayed

def delayed_frame(files, tree_name):
    """create master delayed DataFrame from multiple files"""
    @delayed
    def single_frame(file_name, tree_name):
        """read external file, convert to pandas.DataFrame, return it"""
        tree = uproot.open(file_name).get(tree_name)
        return tree.pandas.df() ## this is the pd.DataFrame
    return dd.from_delayed([single_frame(f, tree_name) for f in files])

def save_selected_frames(df, selections, prefix):
    """perform queries on a delayed DataFrame and save HDF5 output"""
    queries = {sel_name: df.query(sel_query)
               for sel_name, sel_query in selections.items()]
    computes = []
    for dfname, df in queries.items():
        outname = f"{prefix}_{dfname}.h5"
        computes.append(df.to_hdf(outname, f"/{prefix}", compute=False))
    dask.compute(*computes)


selections = {"s1": "(A == True) & (N > 1)",
              "s2": "(B == True) & (N > 2)",
              "s3": "(C == True) & (N > 3)"}

from glob import glob
df = delayed_frame(glob("/path/to/files/*.root"), "selected")
save_selected_frames(df, selections, "selected")

## expect output files:
##  - selected_s1.h5
##  - selected_s2.h5
##  - selected_s3.h5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the HDF library that you're using isn't entirely threadsafe?  If you don't mind losing parallelism then you could add `scheduler="single-threaded"` to the compute call.

You might want to consider using Parquet rather than HDF.  It has fewer issues like this.